# Data not being updated after change the placeID in flutter BLoC

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I am working on one project with BLoC.I have made some classes to update the data.
Data will come once you pass the placeID.
But once you pass the PlaceID first time it will give the data and widgets updated.
But once I pass new placeID old data not being updated. It shows old data.

**All Code Files:**

**RestaurantDetailBloc.dart**

```
class RestaurantDetailBloc extends Bloc<RestaurantDetailEvent, RestaurantDetailState> {
  static final RestaurantDetailBloc _restaurantDetailBlocSingleton = new RestaurantDetailBloc._internal();
  factory RestaurantDetailBloc() {
    return _restaurantDetailBlocSingleton;
  }
  RestaurantDetailBloc._internal();
  RestaurantDetailState get initialState => new UnRestaurantDetailState();
  @override
  Stream<RestaurantDetailState> mapEventToState(
    RestaurantDetailEvent event,
  ) async* {
    try {
      yield await event.applyAsync(currentState: currentState, bloc: this);
    } catch (_, stackTrace) {
      print('$_ $stackTrace');
      yield currentState;
    }
  }
}
```

**LoadRestaurantDetailEvent.dart**

```
@immutable
abstract class RestaurantDetailEvent {
  Future<RestaurantDetailState> applyAsync(
      {RestaurantDetailState currentState, RestaurantDetailBloc bloc});
      final RestaurantDetailProvider _provider = RestaurantDetailProvider();
}

class LoadRestaurantDetailEvent extends RestaurantDetailEvent {
  @override
  String toString() => 'LoadRestaurantDetailEvent';
   String placeID;
   LoadRestaurantDetailEvent({Key key,this.placeID});
  @override
  Future<RestaurantDetailState> applyAsync(
      {RestaurantDetailState currentState, RestaurantDetailBloc bloc}) async {
    try {
      await Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 2));
      var component = await _provider.getRestaurantReview(placeID); 
      print(component);
      return new InRestaurantDetailState(component);
    } catch (_, stackTrace) {
      print('$_ $stackTrace');
      return new ErrorRestaurantDetailState(_?.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

**RestaurantDetailPage.dart**

```
class RestaurantDetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String routeName = "/restaurantDetail";
  final String imageURL;
  final String placeID;
  const RestaurantDetailPage({Key key, this.imageURL,this.placeID}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _restaurantDetailBloc = new RestaurantDetailBloc();
    return  new RestaurantDetailScreen(restaurantDetailBloc: _restaurantDetailBloc,imageUrl: this.imageURL,placeId: this.placeID,);
  }
}
```

**RestaurantDetailProvider.dart**

```
class RestaurantDetailProvider {

String getBaseUrl(String placeID){
    final urlBase = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=$placeID&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxGooglePlaceKey";
    return urlBase;
}

  Future<void> loadAsync(String token) async {
    /// write from keystore/keychain
    await Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 2));
  }

  Future<void> saveAsync(String token) async {
    /// write from keystore/keychain
    await Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 2));
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getRestaurantReview(String placeId)async{
    var response = await http.get(getBaseUrl(placeId));
    RestaurantReviews reviews = RestaurantReviews();

    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      var decodedJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print(decodedJson);

      //reviews.result = decodedJson['result'];
      return decodedJson;
    }
    else{
    }

  }
}
```

**InRestaurantDetailState.dart**

```
@immutable
abstract class RestaurantDetailState extends Equatable {
  RestaurantDetailState([Iterable props]) : super(props);

  /// Copy object for use in action
  RestaurantDetailState getStateCopy();
}

/// UnInitialized
class UnRestaurantDetailState extends RestaurantDetailState {
  @override
  String toString() => 'UnRestaurantDetailState';

  @override
  RestaurantDetailState getStateCopy() {
    return UnRestaurantDetailState();
  }
}

class InRestaurantDetailState extends RestaurantDetailState {

final   resReview;

  InRestaurantDetailState(this.resReview);

  @override
  String toString() => 'InRestaurantDetailState';

  @override
  RestaurantDetailState getStateCopy() {
    return InRestaurantDetailState(resReview);
  }
}

class ErrorRestaurantDetailState extends RestaurantDetailState {
  final String errorMessage;

  ErrorRestaurantDetailState(this.errorMessage);

  @override
  String toString() => 'ErrorRestaurantDetailState';

  @override
  RestaurantDetailState getStateCopy() {
    return ErrorRestaurantDetailState(this.errorMessage);
  }
}
```

**RestaurantDetailScreenState.dart**

```
class RestaurantDetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const RestaurantDetailScreen({
    Key key,
    @required RestaurantDetailBloc restaurantDetailBloc,
    this.imageUrl, this.placeId,
  })  : _restaurantDetailBloc = restaurantDetailBloc,
        super(key: key);

  final RestaurantDetailBloc _restaurantDetailBloc;
  final String imageUrl;
  final String placeId;

  @override
  RestaurantDetailScreenState createState() {
    return new RestaurantDetailScreenState(_restaurantDetailBloc, imageUrl,placeId);
  }
}
class RestaurantDetailScreenState extends State<RestaurantDetailScreen> {
  final RestaurantDetailBloc _restaurantDetailBloc;
  final String imageUrl;
  final String placeId;

  RestaurantDetailScreenState(this._restaurantDetailBloc, this.imageUrl,this.placeId);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    this._restaurantDetailBloc.dispatch(LoadRestaurantDetailEvent(placeID:placeId));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark);
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return BlocBuilder<RestaurantDetailBloc, RestaurantDetailState>(
        bloc: widget._restaurantDetailBloc,
        builder: (
          BuildContext context,
          var currentState,
        ) {
          if (currentState is UnRestaurantDetailState) {
            return MaterialApp(
                home: new Scaffold(
              body: new Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
              ),
            ));
          }
          if (currentState is ErrorRestaurantDetailState) {
            return new Container(
                child: new Center(
              child: new Text(currentState.errorMessage ?? 'Error'),
            ));
          }
          if (currentState is InRestaurantDetailState) {
            var resList = currentState.resReview;
            print(resList);

            return MaterialApp(
              home: new Scaffold(
)
);
}
```

Please help me guys.I have spent whole day.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You need to pass the data to the parent class for comparison. That's why we are using equatable. Do these changes and it should work. Let me know if it doesn’t.**

```
class InRestaurantDetailState extends RestaurantDetailState {

 final   resReview;

 //You need to change this line to
 InRestaurantDetailState(this.resReview):super([resReview]);

 @override
 String toString() => 'InRestaurantDetailState';

 @override
 RestaurantDetailState getStateCopy() {
  return InRestaurantDetailState(resReview);
 }
}
```

Comment: Great sir , Its working fine but the circular progress bar is not showing me. New data has been updated. Any idea for this.